# FParsec operator precedence parser conflicting with next parser in sequence

Tags: fparsec

I have an operator presedence parser that parses mathematical expressions, similar to the calculator example in the FParsec repository.

The next parser in the sequence, however, parses `->` which is causing conflicts with the subtraction operator.

Some representative code is:

```ml
open FParsec

let ws = spaces
let str s = pstring s .>> ws
let number = pfloat .>> ws

let opp = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<float,unit,unit>()
let expr = opp.ExpressionParser
opp.TermParser <- number <|> between (str "(") (str ")") expr

opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("+", ws, 1, Associativity.Left, (+)))
opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("-", ws, 1, Associativity.Left, (-)))
opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("*", ws, 2, Associativity.Left, (*)))
opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("/", ws, 2, Associativity.Left, (/)))
opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("^", ws, 3, Associativity.Right, fun x y -> System.Math.Pow(x, y)))
opp.AddOperator(PrefixOperator("-", ws, 4, true, fun x -> -x))

let completeExpression = expr .>> ws

let program =
    pipe3 completeExpression (str "->") completeExpression <| fun e1 _ e2 ->
        (e1, e2)
```

Which doesn't work for, for example, `1+1 -> 1+2`.

I know that if I change `str "->"` to `str "=>"` then something like `1+1 => 1+2` would work.

Is it possible to add look-ahead into the operator precedence parser? Or is there another way round this?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

I sorted this by adding a `notFollowedBy` in the after-string parser for the subtraction operator.

```ml
let after = (notFollowedBy (str ">")) >>. ws
opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("-", after, 1, Associativity.Left, (-)))
```